# Ruby - LoadError: cannot load such file -- ../credentials_go_in_var_lib/credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one project in which ruby is used. I have one file status.rb below are some code of this file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rest-client'
require 'base64'
require 'pg'
require 'cgi'
require 'json'

require 'tzinfo'
require 'date'

require '../credentials_go_in_var_lib_havesomefun/credentials'
```

Path of project

> /home/microsoft/sites/project

Path of status.rb file

> /home/microsoft/sites/project/linux/dashboard/status.rb

Path of credentials.rb file

> /home/microsoft/sites/project/linux/credentials_go_in_var_lib/credentials.rb

I am executing command of ruby with

```
 ruby linux/dashboard/status.rb
```

I am getting below error

> Traceback (most recent call last):    2: from
>   linux/dashboard/status.rb:14:in `<main>'  1: from
>   /home/microsoft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in`
>   require'
>   /home/microsoft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in
>   `require': cannot load such file --
>   ../credentials_go_in_var_lib/credentials (LoadError)

If all files are in same directory then it can easily load file of credentials.

Please anyone guide what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `require` you need to use `require_relative` because the location of the file is relative to the file you are in

```
require_relative '../credentials_go_in_var_lib_havesomefun/credentials'
```